# How to return index of element after finding the maximum value

Tags: python

I have a matrix [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0][1 0 0 1 0 0 1][2 1 0 0 1 0 0]].I need to return the index of element which is largest in the last row but less than 2 also,the it should return the index which is of highest value.

For example,in my matrix,I need the program to return me M[2,4],2,4 as the solution.My program is running,but it is returning the value at M[2,1] position.

```
M=[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [2 1 0 0 1 0 0]]
    ma=0
    for i in range(1,2):
        for j in range(0,7):
            if M[i,j]<2 and ma<=M[i,j]:
                ma=M[i,j]
                return M[i,j],i,j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is it returns too early. You should make it return after all the elements has been scanned. In this case the return statement should not be placed inside the inner loop, put it outside the outer for loop. Also I think you need to keep track of the highest value's index along with `ma` since i, j would be the value of the last element after the loop finished.

The original code's syntax seems incorrect so I have made some modifications:

```
def test():
    M=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
            [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
    ma=0
    maxi = maxj = 0
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,7):
            if M[i][j] < 2 and ma <= M[i][j]:
                ma = M[i][j]
                maxi = i
                maxj = j
    return(ma, maxi, maxj)

print(test())
```

This code outputs the desired result: `(1, 2, 4)`

Comment: It is returning correct M[i,j] but i,j values are not correct.After following your suggestion,it is returning me (1, 2, 6)

Comment: Oops, forgot that the value of i, j would change in every inner loop. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a way out..I am unable to figure it.

Comment: @SayaneShome No problem, see my latest answer.